# Matrix Multiplication along specified array dimension with R/Rcpp

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, rcpp

Given an `n` dimensional array `X`, a `d` by `d-1` dimensional matrix `V` and two specified dimensions `(p1, p2) <= (n, n)`; I would like a function that preforms matrix multiplication of `V` along the dimensions `(p1, p2)` of `X`.

That is given `X`:

```
library(abind)
set.seed(4)
X <- matrix(runif(4), 2, 2)
X <- abind(x, x+5, along = 3)
> a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    8
[2,]    7    9
```

and given a matrix `V`

```
V <- matrix(c(1, 2))
      [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
```

For example, if `p1=2` and `p2=1`  I would like to remove the following for loop

```
p1 <- 1
p2 <- 2
a.out <- array(0, c(2, 1, 2))
for (i in 1:dim(a)[2]){
  a.out[,,i] <- a[,,i]%*%V # note indexed along other dimension 
}

> a.out
, , 1

     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]   10

, , 2

     [,1]
[1,]   22
[2,]   25
```

The hard part here is that I want to allow for arbitrary dimensional arrays (i.e., `n` could be greater than 3).

**1st Edit:**
This problem is not the same as [Indexing slice from 3D Rcpp NumericVector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378980/indexing-slice-from-3d-rcpp-numericvector) as I am discussing arbitrary number of dimensions >=2 and the question is not only about indexing.

**2nd Edit:**
Just to be a little more clear here is another example of what I am trying to do.  Here the dimension of `X` is 4, `p1 = 2`, `p3=3`, and the dimension of `X` along the `p1` dimension is 12. The following code computes the desired result as `X.out` for random `X` and `V`.

```
X <- array(rnorm(672), c(4, 7, 12, 2))
V <- matrix(rnorm(132), 12, 11) # p1 = 2, p2 = 3, V is of dimension D x D-1
d <- dim(X)
X.out <- array(0, dim=c(d[1:2], d[3]-1, d[4]))
for(i in 1:d[1]){
  for (j in 1:d[4]){
    X.out[i,,,j] <- X[i,,,j]%*%V # p1 = 2, p2 = 3
  }
}
```

Comment: So do all dimensions of _n_-dimensional array `X` have the same size? Is the size `d`? The matrix `V` is _2_-dimensional (by definition of matrix) of size _d_  by _d-1_?

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you for clarifying! No they do not all have the same size. They have arbitrary size. Except for the p2 dimension which has size `d`.

Comment: @coatless How is this a duplicate of that? I am asking about arbitrary number of dimensions >=2 and I am not just asking about indexing.

Comment: @jds read Dirk's response. Basically, you'll need to use RcppArmadillo's [`arma::cube`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube) structure.

Comment: @coatless does that work for more than 3 dimensions? His wording makes it seem pretty clear that it does not. Even my "unedited" question made it clear I was talking about potentially higher dimensional arrays.

Comment: @coatless also, how do you handle having arbitrary dimensions along which to multiply? Its not always the same dimensions or number of dimensions each time. so a simple for loop is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Not too many among us care about _arbitrarity large_ numbers of dimensions.  Maybe the still very new-ish [xtensor](https://cran.r-project.org/package=xtensor) package can help.

Comment: I would be happy with a solution that worked for up to 6 dimensions as it is unlikely that I would need to go beyond that for most cases. Really the hard part for me is having p1 and p2 being variable.

Comment: To clarify a previous comment of mine. It should read "No they do not all have the same size. They have arbitrary size. Except for the `p1` dimension which has size `d`"

Comment: Thinking about it...  I feel like the best way to go about this is to use Fortran as it allows for scaling input. If you want to pursue the _C++_ route, I would suggest [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html). Alternatively, you could likely try out `Blitz` (supports up to N = 11 dimensions), however, development is dead and there lacks any glue between its _C++_ objects and _R_'s.

Comment: Which is why I suggested [xtensor](https://cran.r-project.org/package=xtensor) which does that too and is on CRAN today (but requires C++14 which not everybody may have).