# R matrix memory representation

Tags: c, r

I'm writing a plugin for R and I want to allocate a 3-dimensional R matrix to return. How can I do this? In `Rinternals.h` I see an `allocMatrix` and an `alloc3DArray`. Do I use one of those?

If it is too annoying, I can accept a matrix from the user, but I need to know what the internal representation is so that I can fill it in.

Thank you.

Comment: are you looking for `x <- array(dim=c(4,5,6))`

Comment: Yes, but how do I allocate this from a C extension? And then how can I fill in the values (e.g. by doing x[1,1,1] = 7) from C?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569992/constructing-3d-array-in-rcpp

Comment: Thanks Gary. This is exactly the answer that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems seem at issue. One is validating input from a user and the other is allocation. I would be surprised if it were very much faster to use the `.Call` interface or an rcpp strategy than just allocation with :

```
obj <- array(NA, dim=c(x,y,z)) # where the x,y and z values would be user input.
```

If you look at the code for `array` you see this as the likely workhorse function:

```
if (is.atomic(data) && !is.object(data)) 
    return(.Internal(array(data, dim, dimnames)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth understanding that arrays in R are really just vectors with a dimension attribute set:

```
> x <- array(0, c(2, 2, 2))
> .Internal(inspect(x))
@7f859baf5ee8 14 REALSXP g0c4 [NAM(2),ATT] (len=8, tl=0) 0,0,0,0,0,...
ATTRIB:
  @7f85a1d593c0 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @7f859c8043f8 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,LCK,gp=0x4000] "dim" (has value)
    @7f85a4040bc0 13 INTSXP g0c2 [NAM(2)] (len=3, tl=0) 2,2,2
```

So if you want to make a matrix, or array, 'by hand', it's as simple as allocating a vector of the correct length, and then setting the dimension attribute. Eg:

```
SEXP myArray = PROTECT(allocVector(REALSXP, m * n * k));
SEXP myDims = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, 3));
setAttrib(myArray, R_DimSymbol, myDims);
```